# How to add Pagination with JSON data in collectionview in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, pagination, collectionview

we need to pass **count** in JSON parameter like this

```
var currentPageNumberVM: Int = 0
 "count": currentPageNumber
```

**and in service call I'm getting JSON data like below** here JSON data is coming and data is showing in `collectionview` but pagination is not working

```
func serviceCall(){
self.currentPageNumberVM+=10

let param = ["jsonrpc": "2.0",
             "params": ["type" : type, "count": currentPageNumberVM]] as [String : Any]

APIReqeustManager.sharedInstance.serviceCall(param: param, vc: self, url: getUrl(of: .productByFeature), header: header) {(responseData) in
    if responseData.error != nil{
        self.view.makeToast(NSLocalizedString("Something went wrong!", comment: ""))
    }else{
            self.viewmoreDB = ViewMoreBase(dictionary: responseData.dict as NSDictionary? ?? NSDictionary())
            self.productsData = self.viewmoreDB?.result?.products
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
      
    }
}
}
```

**I'm adding values to `collectionview` like below**

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return productsData?.count ?? 0
 }

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HorizontalSliderCollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! HorizontalSliderCollectionCell
let indexData = productsData?[indexPath.item]
   
cell.lblDescrip.text = indexData?.product_by_language?.des
cell.lblTitle.text = indexData?.product_by_language?.title

return cell
}
```

**for pagenation i am trying like below**: but nothing works

```
var isLoading = false

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        let contentHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height

        if (offsetY > contentHeight - scrollView.frame.height * 4) && !isLoading {
            loadMoreData()
        }
    }

func loadMoreData() {
        if !self.isLoading {
            self.isLoading = true
            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                // Fake background loading task for 2 seconds
                sleep(2)
                // Download more data here
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                    self.isLoading = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

How to add pagination to `collectionview`? .. I mean after loading 10 cells..below need to show activityindicator.. and load another 10 cells

how to do this, please do help me

Comment: What's the point of sleep(2)?  That's something that you rarely use in any programming language unless you literally need to slow down the speed of execution.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this? but first, note that you need to pass the counter as a parameter in your call service function:

This code will be added in your `cellForItemAt` :

```
 let lastPost = postsArray.count - 1
    if lastPost == indexPath.row {
        if limit < 100{
            limit += 10
            callAPI()
        }
```

while `callAPI` function is:

```
func callAPI () {
    PostService.getPosts(limit: limit) { (postsArray, error) in
        
        if error == nil {
            guard let postsArray = postsArray else {return}
            self.postsArray = postsArray
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.postsCollectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

Of course, you will change the naming dependent on your project.
Hope it helps